# the array cube is gone and they are all sticked together

Tags: animation, mesh, rigid-body-simulation

so I Was trying to do some ice cube here I just created a cube and array it many times and on top of each other , I than created a wire cube and rigid body passive and mesh , than plane rigid body passive and mesh , than I added a cube sculpt it to look like an ice, I Than Put it inside one of the array cube and tried to ctrl J To join the ice cube and the one of the array cube so I can Make them all the same but its weird what happened is when I Did that the the array cube are all stick together inside as u can see in the picture they are all on top of each other (before I applied rigid body than removed it so I can make the cube randomly on the plane so I can stop the animation ) I probably missed something on the rigid body or so , and I hope u got what I Meant because its kind of complicated , thanks in advance [image]

Comment: The rigid body simulation won't deform the mesh. So if you want them fall apart they have to be separate objects. In Edit mode press P then select separate by Loose Parts.

Comment: yes i did this  but the problem is after i did this the cube are all inside of each other like they are not seperate anymore they are like this as u can see the with the shadow on it there are the array , this happened after i press ctrl j

Comment: If you press ctrl+j they aren't separate anymore. Don't do that. They must have a name in the Outliner one by one.

Comment: oh okay i got you , but the weird thing is even when  i exit blender so i can go back to the original before i press ctrl j when the cubes are fine together and all together , i cant even see them like original its like this in the picture